# Why can XSLT not parse this XML?

Tags: xml, xslt, browser

Taking the XSLT and XML from this page as an example:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp

I have an xml file which contains (above example modified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
<catalog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <cd>
```

In my case, the output contains nothing when the XSLT/XML is processed by the browser. The moment I remove the attributes from the  element, it works. Problem is, I don't really have the option of pre-processing those attributes out of the file.

Can anyone explain how to force the XSLT to work with the XML as is, please? After all, those attributes seem fairly standard.

Many thanks,

Matt.

Comment: Re: w3schools: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: But do you want to build your own XSLT to transform a XML file? Or just to open it with the browser?

Comment: This is the most answered FAQ about XPath: in XPath 1.0 a QName test without prefix selects elements under the null or empty namespace, then **you need to bind some prefix with a namespace URI and add this prefix to the XPath expression** in order to select an element under a not null nor empty namespace URI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add that default namespace to the stylesheet as well, and use it.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: As declared in the XML, the default namespace is `http://tempuri.org/`. If you don't use that namespace in the XSLT then you can't *see* any of the XML, much less process it.

Comment: @Matt: the default namespace is defined by the xmlns attribute that doesn't define a prefix.

Comment: Thank you both, but I don't see how to use it in the XSLT.

Comment: @Matt: How did you declare the `xsl` namespace in the stylesheet?

Comment: <xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"
    >

Comment: Hmm, added by the stackoverflow editor tool. Read as though they are not there - they're not in my code.

Comment: You should use backquotes with anything you want to be considered as code in SO.

Comment: Also, try giving the namespace a non-null identifier and using that with the elements and attributes in the stylesheet.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying here - I just don't understand how to use the identifier with the elements in the stylesheet.

Comment: Put `xmlns:msws="http://tempuri.org/"`, and where you currently have `cd` use `msws:cd`, and so on.

Comment: The XML is not produced by me. I can't amend it using XSLT because of the above problem. So I don't see how I can modify the element names.

Comment: You don't touch the XML *at all*. You modify the XSLT so that it can read the XML properly.

Comment: I believe we have a gravity applied to penny situation.
Many thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the default namespace of `<cd>` with your declaration basically to

```
<{http://tmpuri.org}:cd>
```

which will not be matched by the the unmodified style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

What Ignacio is saying that your document is defined within a namespace. As a consequence, inside your stylesheet, you can only match on the fully qualified name.

If the XSLT stylesheet is matching on the local name only:

```
<xsl:template match="cd">
...
</xsl:template>
```

then it will never be matched. However, if you put this in the root element of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:catalog="http://tempuri.org/">
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

... and use the qualified name to match, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="catalog:cd">
...
</xsl:template>
```

... then it works.